# Full reflective subcategories of CAT

Tags: category-theory

**CAT** is known to have plenty of full reflective subcategories: e.g. all discrete categories, all single-object categories, all groupoids, all thin categories, and intersections thereof, constitute such subcategories. Each of them, as well as many others, satisfies the following property: the reflection arrow for any non-empty category is surjective on objects. Does **CAT** have a full reflective subcategory that fails to satisfy this property?

Comment: Just to be sure, are we looking at CAT as a 1-category?

Comment: @Mark: yes, exactly.

Comment: One thought: suppose $C$ is a reflective subcategory of CAT. Suppose that if $J \in C$, then all full subcategories of $J$ are also in $C$. Then the reflective arrows are always surjective on objects. So if you were to come up with a counterexample, you'd need some $C$ which isn't closed under full subcategories. The examples you've come up with are all closed under the full subcategories.

Comment: @Mark: I must admit I’m unable to figure out how closedness under the formation of full subcategories implies surjectivity of the reflective arrows on objects. Could you please explain or provide a reference?

Comment: In the meantime, I found out that the hypothetical counterexample in question would consist of gaunt categories (those that do not have non-identity isomorphisms) and contain at least one non-thin category. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: Suppose $K : A \to B$ is a reflective arrow. Then in particular, consider the full subcategory $B’$ of $B$ consisting of the image of $K$ on objects. Then consider $K’ : A \to B’$. There is a unique $J : B \to B’$ such that $K’ = J \circ K$, and you can show that $J$ and the inclusion map are inverse isomorphisms. So $B’ = B$, and thus $K$ is surjective on objects.

Comment: @Mark: ah, you implicitly appeal to the factorization structure (E, M) for functors in **CAT**, where E is the class of all functors that are surjective on objects and M is the class of all inclusions of full subcategories. Applying the reflector to the (E, M)-factorization of the reflection arrow, you show that the latter belongs to E whenever the reflective subcategory is closed under full subcategories.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to phrase it (and a good analogy for other categories like Set where the same thing works for the same reason).